# Safari iPad full screen screenshot is not showing full page, blank lines in resulting screenshot

Tags: ios, ipados

Device: ipad 12.9, ios 16.5.1 (c).

On safari while browsing https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama/blob/main/llama/model.py I tried to take full screen screenshot .

Screenshot link:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QZuotetqN-lgdM9l4ZQxiH0ra34voLAJ/view?usp=sharing

In provided screenshot link  while scrolling down one can see in the pdf file line 75 to 125 is showing blank compare to the url i was browsing.

how to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm able to replicate the issue. It's indeed quite weird since this seems to be only on this specific page (no problem with https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama-recipes/blob/main/llama_finetuning.py for example).

Comment: I tried with link you mentioned but same problem, scroll down and you'll see line 145-164 are blank https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c0VBBxw1jMM4bI4By0L8jI1yDW9KWH2e/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Um. Weirdly enough, I did not get this gap the first time I checked but now I get it. Maybe I just missed it? I also managed to reduce the gap in the linked page (in the question) by changing my iPad's orientation. Gap from lines 143 to 215 in landscape mode and from lines 168 to 215 in portrait mode.

Comment: Not sure why but full screen screentshot output slightly differs depending upon how much you have scrolled through the webpage that one is trying to take full screen screenshot of.

Comment: I've noticed that too. This never happened to me before, did it happen before for you?

Comment: Actually i recently got a pencil to take notes and found out this useful feature, but for slightly large pages facing this issue.

Comment: Oh, so this already happened? I've just tested on Chrome and it's even worse, blank from lines 115 to 215!